# How to assign dataframe to dynamic variable to python?

Tags: python, pandas

As a part of code,I need to assign a dataframe to a dynamic variable created during the process.

I did research on assigning value as below:

```
I = 1
x = 'varName'+str(I)
exec("%s = %d" % (x,2))

varName1
```

But how to do it for dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: python 2.7? 3.x? you should look into dict's, I'm not a big fan of evals and execs it makes the code unreadable for one and I believe it's not a good practice. A dict might be exactly what you want it's essentially a hash table that allows you to assign a key to a value {key: value} or in your case a string of a name to a DataFrame. You could add a little bit more explanation of the problem itself you are trying to solve with a less conceptual and more practical code example.

Answer (score 0):

"dynamic variables" are an antipattern. What you want is either a `dict`:

```
vars = {}
key = "something_%s" % another_string
vars[key] = something()
```

or (more probably since you seem to be using some numeric index):

```
vars = []
for whatever in (some_sequence):
    val = something(whatever) 
    vars.append(val)
```

which FWIW can be rewritten more simply as :

```
vars = [something(whatever) for whatever in some_sequence]
```